# Keycloak fails to authenticate openid-connect token in cluster mode

Tags: session, keycloak, cluster-computing

I'm running two keycloak docker instances and configured cluster as specified here https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

I can able see logs related to clustering and two records in `JGROUPSPING` table. Also it works when authenticate(openid-connect) through Host1 and get access token/refresh token and able to retrieve new access_token using refresh token via Host2, which means I believe clustering setup is working.

But Im getting 401 error when I make API call to Host2 either using the access token I received from Host1 or access_token I got from Host1's refresh token. It works only when I use access_token received from same host.

My understanding is that these access_tokens doesn't related to cookie it should be working seamlessly. But it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with the verification of the access token signature.

The access token are signed by Keycloak with a keystore. If you don't have a certificate and key mounted in the docker, this keystore will be different between the nodes in your cluster, and a token generated by one node will not be valid for another node.

So you have to follow the "Setting up TLS(SSL)" part of the documentation of the docker.